sqlx data type enforcment mitigation
Using rust and sqlx (PostgreSQL & MySQL)
Im trying to create a tool that can be compiled with either MySQL or PostgreSQL as storage.
I have a users table with an id field, which would be of type varchar in the MySQL schema and uuid in the PostgreSQL schema.
To use sqlx macros, I have data model structs for each entity.
The issue is: when using postgreSQL sqlx insists that id would be of type Uuid since that is the data type of that field in the sql table.
And in the case of MySQL sqlx insists that the type would be String.
pub struct User {
    id: Uuid, // vs id: String
    name: String,
    email: String,
}

query_as!(
    User,
    r#"SELECT * from users"#,
    id,
)

The User struct can not be shared between the DB adapters, and duplicate auxiliary structs needs to be created - Which seems very off and can not be propagated through the entire data model structs code.
Any suggestions on how to mitigate the issue?
From the rust data struct, I dont really care about UUID or String, I'm fine with it being a String in the rust code, and have the postgreSQL enforce UUID on the id field internally.

Infer column type from struct field?
